# connect remotely to apache2 on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ubuntu-10.04, remote-access

I've apache2 server installed on a machine that connected to two different networks, therefore it has two different addresses: 192.168.1.111 (static ip on ethernet network) and 109.253.78.211.
when connecting through 109.253.78.211 on the browser, the web pages are displayed perfectly, However, when connecting through 192.168.1.111 the web pages are displayed partially.
I've not installed any firewalls.
I'll really appreciate if you could redirect me to checks I should commit to reach the source of the problem.

Thank you :)

Comment: _when connecting through 109.253.78.211 on the browser, the web pages are displayed perfectly, However, when connecting through 109.253.78.211 the web pages are displayed partially._ What does that mean?

Comment: that when using one address to connect to the server it works great and the web pages (php) that related to the server are displayed perfectly. on the other hand, when trying to connect from the ethernet  address the web browser does not display the web pages as they should be. is it more clear now?

Comment: can you show us some html code which gets delivered

Comment: It's php code, I can show you. However, I don't believe the code is problematic since using the other connection the web pages are well displayed

Comment: What @SamKrieg was pointing out is that you've used the same address for "this works" as for "this doesn't work".  Please clarify which address works and which doesn't.  It seems like you're intending to say that the 109.253.78 address works, and the 192.168.1 address does not work?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the base page is loading, but elements of it are not, I would suggest using a tool like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools to take a look at the reason that some elements are failing to load.

A likely cause would be an issue with relative vs absolute linking for those objects, especially if the application is requiring authentication to load resources -- take a look at the URL that the resources are loading from, and make sure that it's valid.

Comment: thank you, i've used the firebug and got to the conclusion that the problem is with displaying certain flash files